# What happens if the upload key is lost when using Google Play App Signing?

Tags: android, google-play, signing

If I use [Google Play App Signing](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#manage-key) and I lose the upload key, what happens?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I'm glad you asked, there is no need to worry if you lose the upload key. You can generate a new one. From Google's [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#manage-key):

> When you use Google Play App Signing, if you lose your upload key, or if it is compromised, you can contact Google to revoke your old upload key and generate a new one. Because your app signing key is secured by Google, you can continue to upload new versions of your app as updates to the original app, even if you change upload keys.

Comment: @ruben When you submit a question you can choose to answer it at the same time. I posted this here for the benefit of others.

Comment: So your answer is to read the documentation/help pages, I wouldn't really say thats an answer more common sense?

Comment: @MarkKeen True, but given the documentation is a bit scattered (there is also documentation here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en ) and this is a sufficiently important detail, I think it is worth having it as it's own question. I personally had to do some digging for the answer and hopefully this will save others the time.

Comment: Strange - I typed in google `play store what happens if i lose my api signing key` and it was first hit - `Manage your app signing keys` (which is link you just gave) with docs and all information including link you referred to in your answer - that isn't scattered? It's fine - leave your answer in, but in all seriousness I fail to see how it required "digging" for.

Comment: @MarkKeen I used "digging" a bit too loosely. I guess it comes down to is it better that this question and answer exist on SO or not. I tend to think yes because the more questions and answers the better. But of course we don't want SO flooded with trivial questions that can be answered by simply reading the documentation, which to your point, this is. This gets at the core of what SO is and frankly it is above my reputation grade. I'd be curious what meta.stackoverflow thinks.

Comment: Before using a new upload key, do I have to inform google in some way or other. Or I can just change the upload key and upload the apk.

Comment: How long does it usually take for the request to be approved?