# Can't update app in Google Play (apk was signed in debug mode). Probably keystore problems

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, build, android-keystore

When I created my first app for Android (with Unity 2018, by the way), I knew nothing about keystores. So my game was built with default unsigned(debug) signing.

As I realise now, Developer Console shouldn't allow to publish APK's with debug.keystore. But that day the app was somehow published. I was even able to update my app several times with the APK's that have the same debug.keystore.

But from today I'm no longer able to update apps. When I upload new APK, the error appears:

*"You uploaded an APK that was signed in debug mode. You need to sign your APK in release mode"*

At first I thought that there's something wrong with my new versions. But when I tried to upload the old APK (actually the same APK's, that were already uploaded and published), the same error occured!

So I understood that the problem is not with my APK's. Something changed in Developer Console. 2 days ago it allowed me to publish APK with debug.keystore and now doesn't

So the main questions are:

1. **Why Developer console allowed me to publish APK's that was signed with default debug.keystore?**
2. **Why from today it stopped allowing it**
3. **What should I do to be able to update my app again?**

Also need to mention, that I've already tried creating new keystore. In this case the error doesn't appear. But the other error occurs, meaning that APK could not be uploaded to Developer Console, because new keys doesn't match with old

And yes, I am using Google App Signing.

And no, Unity build is not set in "development build", MV Studio is also in release mode.

Comment: [The documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#debug-mode) explictly states that Google Play will not accept an APK signed with a debug certificate. Why you were able to publish such APKs before, I don't know.  _"What should I do to be able to update my app again"_. You can't. At least not in such a way that users that already have your app will be able to update to the new version. You may be able to publish your new version as an entirely new app (different package name). Or you may be able to publish it as the same app if you unpublish all existing versions.

Comment: Although, it's not entirely clear if the key you're talking about is your app signing key, or your upload key. If it's app signing key, then see my previous comment. If it's the upload key, you may be able to replace it (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49470722/what-happens-if-the-upload-key-is-lost-when-using-google-play-app-signing).

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error here.
From what I have found, there is a problem with new Android SDK missing a tool or so to extract keys (release key) from your keystore.
I haven't found a solution yet, some suggest downgrade SDK but didn't help me.

Comment: I am now trying to find help from Google Support. If something gets clear, I'll write it here. And if you find the solution, pls let me know as well :)

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

i was have the same problem today,looks like android is signing the apk with debug key by default.  i get the answer here:
[Google Play error when uploading Flutter app debuggable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51688791/google-play-error-when-uploading-flutter-app-debuggable)

add into android/app/build.gradle in the android section the follow:

```
 signingConfigs {
            release {
                storeFile file("xxpath/release.jks")
                storePassword= "******"
                keyAlias= "******"
                keyPassword= "******"
            }
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
        }
```