# Flutter release apk not accepted by Google Play Console

Tags: android, flutter, google-play-console

I created a key and keystore and signed my apk, following the instructions step by step from the [official flutter page.](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android)

But when I try to upload it to Google Play Console, I get this error:

> "You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle that was signed in debug mode. You need to sign your APK or Android App Bundle in release mode"

[A similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51688791/google-play-error-when-uploading-flutter-app-debuggable?noredirect=1&lq=1) is asked before, but it did not solve my issue.

Here is the relevant part of my app/build.gradle:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 28

lintOptions {
    disable 'InvalidPackage'
}

defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "my.package.name"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    //testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
        keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
        storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
        storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release

        minifyEnabled true
        useProguard true

        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Here is the screenshot of my Android Studio versions (Android SDK being red is not relevant.):

[image: Screenshot of Android Studio showing the used versions.]

My output.json file:

```
[
  {
    "outputType": {
      "type": "APK"
    },
    "apkInfo": {
      "type": "MAIN",
      "splits": [
        
      ],
      "versionCode": 1,
      "versionName": "1.0.0",
      "enabled": true,
      "outputFile": "app-release.apk",
      "fullName": "release",
      "baseName": "release"
    },
    "path": "app-release.apk",
    "properties": {
      
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No suggestions seemed to be working. Then, a

> flutter clean

and all issues were solved. I could create an apk either through Android Studio or the command line. Thanks to VikaS and Harsha pulikollu

Comment: Thanks, I save my night

Answer (score 2):

You need to select `release` option while building APK

**For Windows**

[image]

**For Apple**

[image]

Comment: I can't see imgur images, sorry (They're banned in my country for some reason). If you mean "flutter build apk --release", that's how I signed them. But it makes no difference.

Comment: I used vpn and saw the images. But from where do I get to that window? Every forum I looked says to use the terminal command. I searched in Android Studio with "find action", but it's not enabled for me. I can not click it.

Comment: check this video https://drive.google.com/open?id=19IMiDjAjFcyDNMvO1X1juimLNzcYAI2p

Comment: Thanks for the video. But I don't have a "generate signed bundle" option when I click on the "Build" tab. I see "Build Bundles/APKs" but it's not clickable for me. I'm using the latest version of Android Studio.

Comment: what is your Studio version number?

Comment: You have to open your flutter android project into separate android studio then you can genararte apk. Right click on flutter project inside android studio then you will see 'FLUTTER,' hover on it 'Open in android studio'

Comment: Android Studio 3.3.1. Maybe it's not enabled in Flutter Projects?

Comment: try to check update by clicking `check for update` from `help` menu

Comment: I found it with Harshapulikollu's instructions. And built it according to VikaS's video. I loaded the .aap file but no luck. Same error.

Comment: could you please check by selecting both option?

Comment: I tried all combinations of App Bundle/APK and debug/release. No luck :/

Comment: could you please take screenshot of your Studio version and attache to Question....by clicking `About` from `help` menu

Comment: They've been attached.

Comment: check your output.json file inside release folder in android>app> relsease>output.json please upload that also.

Comment: They've been added.

Comment: After poking around for a bit, >Flutter clean solved the issue. No idea why. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: @MelihDurmaz what steps you performed? Please add those in details on Answer, so other members can follow those...It will help them...Just add your steps below my steps...

Answer (score 2):

`flutter clean` did not work for me either. So I manually signed the apk and it was accepted by Google Play Console. Found the directions here https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#sign-manually

### How to manually sign apk

To manually sign the apk you need to run the following commands in a terminal o in command prompt in Windows.

1 - Make sure the apk is signed with debug keys:

`<build-tools-path>/<sdk-vesion>/apksigner verify --print-certs app-release.apk` (replace "app-release.apk" with your apk filename"

If it is signed with debug keys, the output will be similar to

```
Signer #1 certificate DN: C=US, O=Android, CN=Android Debug
Signer #1 certificate SHA-256 digest: 384cf54f892877ea6d934bbc335bf3aa61b8dd3d89e27feb49c0bc7e62b0bbb7
Signer #1 certificate SHA-1 digest: c7a8384ff8fe2d1e99dbdba45db93180ed53b9ff
Signer #1 certificate MD5 digest: ca13ad2688257283319bf2596f360f8c
```

2 - Run zipalign to align first byte and reduce RAM usage

`<build-tools-path>/<sdk-vesion>/zipalign -v -p 4 app-release.apk app-aligned.apk`

It will list the files and finish with a `Verification succesful` message.

3 - Run appsigner to sign the app:

`<build-tools-path>/<sdk-vesion>/apksigner sign --ks <path to .jks file> --out app-signed.apk app-aligned.apk`

It will prompt for the keystore password and silently finish the job.

4 - Verify if it is signed with your keys:

`<build-tools-path>/<sdk-vesion>/apksigner verify --print-certs app-signed.apk`

If it is correctly signed, the output will be similar to the fist step, but instead of "Android Debug" it will output your certificate's data.

Comment: Hello @Ricardo, I have the same problem with React Native 0.60, but I cant fin the build tool path, is it in the Android files ?

Comment: @Friis1978 build-tools is in Android SDK directory. It location may vary depending of how you've installed Android SDK and your OS.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
flutter clean
```

flutter clean command is really helpful in many scenario whenever some absurd behavior is shown by the app.